# Creating a Smudge tool effect in ipad apps

Tags: core-graphics

How to create a smudge tool effect in ipad apps using core graphics?.

Answer (score 1):

Andy Finnell wrote [a blog post about implementing smudge and stamp tools](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/09/05/how-to-implement-smudge-and-stamp-tools/).

Some of the code uses Core Graphics; some of it uses AppKit, which is Mac-specific. Even so, it should be possible for you to port the AppKit bits to UIKit with a bit of work and documentation-checking.

Comment: i looked into this blog before posting this message. I find it hard to port the appkit to uikit as i am new to coregraphics.